Remove character for specific column
I need to remove thousand comma separator (,) in Total Chargeable column. Currently i'm using
line = line.replace(',', ''); but then it will remove all commas.
Any suggestions how we can remove thousand comma without removing separator comma in JavaScript?
File is csv format but view on notepad
Example :
As-Is
"Modem ID","Total Chargeable"
"BF002062010","1,300.00"
"BF002062013","1,900.00"
"VV878443","1,000.00"
"","2,200.00"
"BF002061500","5,300.67"
"BF002062151","2,000.00"

To-Be
"Modem ID","Total Chargeable"
"BF002062010","1300.00"
"BF002062013","1900.00"
"VV878443","1000.00"
"","2200.00"
"BF002061500","5300.67"
"BF002062151","2000.00"


Or, maybe you could use some CSV reader library to looping through the CSV contents like this?
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const writer = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;


const rows = [];

fs.createReadStream('test.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
      let temp = {};
      temp['Modem ID'] = row['Modem ID']
      temp['Total Chargeable'] = row['Total Chargeable'].replaceAll(',', '');

      rows.push(temp);

  })
  .on('end', () => {
      console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
      const csvWriter = writer({
        path: 'output.csv',
        header: Object.keys(rows[0]).map(header => ({ id: header, title: header }))
    });
    csvWriter.writeRecords(rows)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully written with updated data');
    })
  });


Generally the proper solution when dealing with csv, but row['Total Chargeable'].replace(',', '') should be row['Total Chargeable'].replaceAll(',', '') since a number may have multiple commas

Updated my answer, thanks! @HaoWu

One approach will be like this, before replacing the thousand comma, you can replace the separator comma with some other character, then you need to replace all the commas and add the separator comma.
#It will replace separator comma with pipe.
line = line.replaceAll('","', '"|"');

#It will remove all the commas.
line = line.replaceAll(',', '');

#Replace pipe separator with comma.
line = line.replaceAll('"|"', '","');

** One problem i can see with this approach that it will remove the comma from data also if you have any comma in that. But if you don't have that type of data. You can use this.


const data = `
"Modem ID","Total Chargeable"
"BF002062010","1,300.00"
"BF002062013","1,900,000.00"
"VV878443","1,000.00"
"","2,200.00"
"BF002061500","5,300.67"
"BF002062151","2,000.00"
`;

var output = data.replaceAll('","', '"|"');
output = output.replaceAll(',', '');
output = output.replaceAll('"|"', '","');

console.log(output);




This should work for your case, what it does is to remove any comma in between two numbers.


const data = `
"Modem ID","Total Chargeable"
"BF002062010","1,300.00"
"BF002062013","1,900.00"
"VV878443","1,000.00"
"","2,200.00"
"BF002061500","5,300.67"
"BF002062151","2,000.00"
`;

const output = data.replace(/(?<=\d),(?=\d)/g, '');

console.log(output);




We can try the following regex replacement approach:


var input = `"Modem ID","Total Chargeable"
"BF002062010","1,300.00"
"BF002062013","1,900.00"
"VV878443","1,000.00"
"","2,200.00"
"BF002061500","5,300.67"
"BF002062151","2,000.00"`;

var output = input.replace(/".*?"|,/g, (x) => x === "," ? "," : x.replace(/,/g, ""));
console.log(output);



The regex pattern used here says to match:

".*?" first try to match at term in double quotes
| OR
, that failing, match a comma

Then, we use a callback function to selectively strip commas only from the numbers in double quotes, leaving the comma separators alone.

It doesn't work with numbers that have more than one comma tho

@HaoWu Great catch...I also upvoted your answer as it does not merit any downvote.

Although I think it's always better to parse csv through a library though. It will always have some issues if the column contains double quotes, e.g. "Samsung U600 24""","1,234.00"

@HaoWu ... I generally agree with you, and a parser is the safer and more stable way to go.  Take this answer (and most answers to this question) with your caveat.

On the second thought it might be okay. Since there always be even number of quotes on a column. Couldn't think of an example that it could break it.

You can achieve it in JS by doing something like this:
const csvData = `"Modem ID","Total Chargeable"
"BF002062010","1,300.00"
"BF002062013","1,900.00"
"VV878443","1,000.00"
"","2,200.00"
"BF002061500","5,300.67"
"BF002062151","2,000.00"`;

const updatedData = csvData.replace(/"(\d+),(\d{3})(\.\d{2})?"/g, (match, p1, p2, p3) => {
  return `"${p1}${p2}${p3 || ''}"`; 
});

Feel free to use your own logic for regex!

Not my downvote, but it also fails when the number has multiple commas (e.g. "1,000,000.00")
